# What does どぼり mean?

Tags: definitions, onomatopoeia

I know that it's an onomatopoeia, and it's an adverb that can take the と particle.

The context goes something like this. There is an object. The object in question is filled with a liquid. The object also has an opening in it. The liquid spills out, flows out, gushes out, and so on. どぼり(と) is attached to the said action of the liquid.

I looked on Denshi Jisho, and it has nothing on it. I looked on Weblio, and it has nothing on it. I even looked on this one [website](http://thejadednetwork.com/) that lists sound effects, and there was nothing.

So does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「どぼり」 is a variant of 「どぼどぼ」.  The latter should be listed in any good dictionary.  [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%BC%E3%81%A9%E3%81%BC) explains it this way.

> 酒{さけ}をコップに**どぼどぼ**とついだ
>
> The sake made a gurgling sound as he poured it into his cup.

(That English is a "free" translation by the dictionary.  The subject of the original is an unmentioned person and not 酒.)

[Even Jisho has 「ドボドボ」, too](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%BC%E3%81%A9%E3%81%BC).

You might want to remember that many onomatopoeias related to liquid movements will start with a 「**ど + b**」 as in 「どぶん」、「どぼん」、「どばどば」、「どばっ」, etc.

Finally, it is so hot today that I just want to **どぶん**とプールに飛{と}び込{こ}みたい after posting this answer.

Comment: @l’électeur: Oh, thank you! That onomatopoeia had me stumped!