# Does anyone knows the meaning of "モゾリと"?

Tags: meaning, adverbs, onomatopoeia

An example of where it was found:

> 慌てて口元を塞ぎながら、部屋の中で**モゾリと**動いていた影に、慌てて蹴りを入れる。

Answer (score 2):

「モゾリ」 is a variant of the onomatopoeia 「もぞもぞ/モゾモゾ」, which expresses the movement of a thing/creature ***creeping about***.  The 「と」 helps it sound more like an adverb (even though, technically speaking, onomatopoeias can generally function adverbially even without a 「と」).

[Even Jisho has 「もぞもぞ」](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%82%E3%81%9E%E3%82%82%E3%81%9E).

> "While covering my mouth in haste, I quickly gave a kick to that little shadow that was creeping about the room."

I actually answered a similar question here:

[What does どぼり mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/59632/what-does-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%bc%e3%82%8a-mean)